# why wont my python editor work

Tags: python, tkinter

I downloaded pycharm and I copied some code from a youtube tutorial into it which worked for the person making the video but when i tried running it it didnt work and this is what it said:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/wheel/test/test245425232.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/wheel/test/test245425232.py", line 9, in <module>
    button1.bind("<button1>", printName)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1098, in bind
    return self._bind(('bind', self._w), sequence, func, add)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1053, in _bind
    self.tk.call(what + (sequence, cmd))
_tkinter.TclError: bad event type or keysym "button1"

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()

def printName():
    print("hi stuff")

button1=Button(root, text="print my name")
button1.bind("<button1>", printName)
button1.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I think you would have to add tkinter library for this to work.

Answer (score 4):

It's better with :

```
button1.bind("<Button-1>", printName)
```

But you may want to plug your function directly to your button widget, a binding is not necessary here, it can be useful with a label widget for example :

```
button1=Button(root, text="print my name", command=printName)
```

("Button-1" is the name of the mouse left click event, not a widget variable name)

Otherwise you need to declare your function `printName` with a parameter : the event given by your binding.

```
def printName(event):
    print("hi stuff")

button1=Button(root, text="print my name")
button1.bind("<Button-1>", printName)
```

---

Like i said, a binding like this could make sense with another widget :

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()

def printName(event):
    print("hi stuff")

label1=Label(root, text="print my name")
label1.bind("<Button-1>", printName)
label1.pack()
root.mainloop()
```